# With Google+ being shutdown, is the OAuth API gone too?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

A number of our users authenticate through the Google OAuth API (https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth)

What is the future of the Google's version OAuth API beyond the April 2019?

OAuth aside, we use the following endpoint to obtain the user's email and name: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me once we obtain the access token. Is this endpoint becoming obsolete?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Update 12/21/18

[Google+ Shutdown Notice](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown)

[End Update]

OAuth 2.0 is a service provided by Google Accounts. The end of life for Google+ will not affect OAuth 2.0.

OAuth 2.0 is the foundation authentication service for Google Cloud Platform, G Suite and many other services. OAuth 2.0 is token based, and these tokens can be used on a variety of services, both Google based and third party.

A further question was asked below in the comment section about endpoints.

The Google+ endpoint for user information: [googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me](http://googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me) will probably continue to exist for years (awaiting official announcement from Google).

I would start using the Google OAuth 2.0 endpoint (notice the alt=json): https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?alt=json

Which returns Json that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "123456789012345678901",
  "email": "username@example.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "name": "User Name",
  "given_name": "User",
  "family_name": "Name",
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/123456789012345678901",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/.../mo/photo.jpg",
  "locale": "en",
  "hd": "example.com"
}
```

The current list of Google OAuth 2.0 endpoints:

https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: Perhaps I need to be more specific. Is the following endpoint deprecated: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me this is what we currently use to obtain the email, first and last name of the user.

Comment: @Slawomir - Update: This article details what is being shutdown https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown . The endpoint `people/me` is listed as part of the Goole+ REST API that is part of the shutdown.

Comment: Update. I just received the following from Google: "On March 7, 2019, all Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in will be shut down completely. This will be a progressive shutdown, with API calls starting to intermittently fail as early as January 28, 2019, and OAuth requests for Google+ scopes starting to intermittently fail as early as February 15, 2019."

Comment: @JohnHanley https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?alt=json In output there is no key name "id" but user id contains in key name "sub"

Answer (score 3):

> What is the future of OAuth API beyond the April 2019?

Oauth is not an api it is a protocol for authentication. In this instance the authentication response is used to access  googles APIs.  Googles use of Oauth2 for authentication is not going any where there has been no announcement that it is being discontinued in any way.  Nor do i think they would as to my knowledge it is current industry standard for authenticating to APIs

> OAuth aside, we use the following endpoint to obtain the user's email and name: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me once we obtain the access token. Is this endpoint

The Google people api may contain the term plus in the url but it does not really have anything to do with Google plus (other than really bad naming).

***[Documentation]** The [People api](https://developers.google.com/people/)  lets you list and manage the authenticated [user's Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) and retrieve profile information for authenticated users and their contacts.*

Which actually has nothing to do with Google plus other than the fact that some of the users profile information may have originally been contained within Google plus which has now been moved i suspect (but i have no proof of that). *I did send off an email to google asking for some clarification as to exactly which endpoints are shutting down.*

**Shutdown**

So what is going to happen with the shutdown

- [Google+](https://plus.google.com/discover) will stop working
- [plus.activites](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities) will stop working.
- [plus.comments](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/comments) will stop working

What will happen to [people overview](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people) will be a really good question.  They may be renamed however i suspect they may just be left alone to access the google contacts as they do currently. (again i have no proff of this)

**Get current user info**

If you want to get the information about the current user then an idea would be to use the userinfo endpoint.  As long as you requested the profile scope you can request the current users info from the identity server directly

Request:

```
GET /oauth2/v2/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer qMgWQHD0MstTDVip7hIYipUpSQkxexF4-W0bI3geEaYk0ztVryYZyFRrZDFWkn69Hw3RlBjfOuXJ8df_iv5ATgW3y0BUkI0xMXeGq22qmfqG-4duSU
```

Response:

```
{
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg", 
  "name": "Linda Lawton", 
  "family_name": "Lawton", 
  "locale": "en", 
  "gender": "female", 
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton", 
  "given_name": "Linda", 
  "id": "117200475532672775346"
}
```

I suspect that some of this is going to change.  Link for example is not going to be able to link to google plus anymore.  I think i will send off an email to google to see what they intend to do about that.

*Email will only appear in the response if you have also requested email scope when authenticating the user.*

**update**

blog post on api shutdown just went out and gives information on what APIs are being shut down and when.

> The most commonly used APIs that are being shut down include:
>
> - Google+ REST API
> - Google+ Web API
> - Google+ Android SDK
> - Google+ Domains API
> - Google+ Pages API

This still doesn't clear up the issue with the people API being Google contacts yet part of the Google+ rest API

https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-apis-shutting-down-march-7-2019.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer though slightly presumptuous in the first paragraph, but perhaps my question was ambiguous too. Naturally I wasn't referring to the protocol as being discontinued, but the effects of Google+ being decommissioned and how it may affect their OAuth API or the endpoints with the "plus" in them. With 50mln accounts compromised it's uncertain the extend of the shutdown they decide on.

Comment: My answer was written so that it was clear to everyone not presumptuous towards you.  I suspect that others will run across your awesome question over the next few months wanted to be sure there was no confusion.   I got a response back from Google this morning there has been no decision made about the **https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me** endpoint yet.

Comment: Just received a notification that plus.people.get will be decommissioned

Comment: I have linked to the blog post that just went out.   Still no official word on link in the userinfo endpoint response

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo for the list of API being affected!

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable this Google + API from your apps, you need to go to https://console.developers.google.com

... and navigate to each project you are using Google+ Api and click **DISABLE**

This will remove any requests from Google + API.